# Defining vectors in arbitrary basis

Tags: functions, linear-algebra, symbolic, vector

I am a beginner in Mathematica,

Suppose I want to write a series of five vectors $p_1,...,p_5$ in terms of an arbitrary basis spanned by $\left\{p,n\right\}$ with each coefficient in such a decomposition a function of scalar variables.

e.g $$p_i = f_i p + g_i n,$$
with $f_i$ and $g_i$ labelling the scalar functions.

I tried e.g for vector $p_1$,

```
 p1 = -2*k/(x+k)*y*p - (k/x + m/y)*n
```

where k,x,m and y are the scalar variables mentioned and p, n are the vectors. Of course, Mathematica doesn't know to interpret p and n as vectors in the above so I am looking for a way to define $p_1$ explicitly as a vector.

Statements such as

```
  p1 = {-2*k/(x+k)*y, - (k/x + m/y)}
```

are also not interrupted correctly because while this attempt uses vector notation recognised by Mathematica, it doesn't know how to interpret the entries of $\left\{, \right\}$ unless they are just numbers. In any case, I think this notation assumes a Cartesian basis. My basis consists of two vectors $p$ and $n$ with $p \cdot n = 1, p^2 = 0, n^2 =0$.

So how to define vectors $p_i$ in a vector space spanned by $p,n$  with scalar functions as coefficients in Mathematica?

Comment: Are $p$ and $n$ vectors? Is ${p,n} = [p | n]$? Are you looking for $f_i$ and $g_i$? Not clear to me.

Comment: `LinearSolve[Transpose[{p,n}],pi]`.

Comment: @MikeY yes, sorry, p and n are vectors and f and g are the respective coefficients which happen to be scalar functions (not just numbers but functions of several variables). Is it clearer?  Thanks!

Comment: Also,  p and n are such that $p  \cdot n = 1$ and $p^2 = n^2 = 0$ (essentially I'm doing a sudakov decomposition but that I think is irrelevant - I'm coming from a physics background)

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: how does linear solve help here?

Comment: Try an explicit example (which should have been posted to begin with).

Comment: I am not solving for anything, I just want to write five lines in mathematica which defines my vectors $p_1, \dots , p_5$ in terms of the basis vectors $p$ and $n$.  Something like, e.g  $p_1 = \left\{f_1, g_1 \right\}$ seems to assume that the $f_1, g_1$ are numbers and that my basis is Cartesian, neither of which is useful for me.

Comment: It is essential that you specify more clearly what you have tried and what the desired output in *Mathematica* is supposed to be. Otherwise, the question will probably be closed as unclear. I'm guessing you're looking for a symbolic reformatting of some kind, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Jens Please refer to my edit for a hopefully clearer question and my attempts

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the desired output?

Comment: All I want to do is to write five vectors $p_i, i=1,\dots,5$ in terms of basis vectors $p$ and $n$, with $p$ and $n$ satisfying $p \cdot n = 1, p^2=n^2=0$. The vector components of each $p_i$ are scalar functions. Once I have these defined, I then want to perform vector manipulations with them but here I am only asking how to define them. So the desired mathematica output is just output that defines five vectors in terms of the desired basis.

Comment: So ` {-2*k/(x+k)*y, - (k/x + m/y)}` is not what is wanted? This makes it all the more important that some clue be provided as to what a viable result might be.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I tried that but it assumes a cartesian basis. E.g let $p_1 = f_1 p + g_1 n$ and $p_2 = f_2 p + g_2 n$. Then $(p_1+p_2)^2 = (f_1+f_2)^2 + (g_1+g_2)^2$ while I need $(p_1+p_2)^2 = 2(f_1+f_2)(g_1+g_2)$ (the former is the output from mathematica and assumes $p \cdot n = 0$ (i.e cartesian basis) and I need $p \cdot n =1$, which gives the latter)

Comment: My question is a simple one: How to write Mathematica code to represent a vector in terms of an arbitrary basis? The notation v = {x,y} assumes x and y are components in a cartesian basis. I'm not sure how this is not clear in my OP and certainly do not see how it is not clear after the comments above. If it doesn't get reopened, I'll repost my question with what I write in this comment in addition.

Comment: Not much in the way of sample input was provided, and no sample output. I'm looking at it all the same, but absent a notion of what this representation should be, it's not so easy to offer anything.

Comment: Embed in a polynomial ring using components for vectors `p` and `n`, define relations based on the three dot products thereof, and use them to reduce dot products involving the `pi`. Example:`In[37]:= pvec = Array[p, 2];
nvec = Array[n, 2];
p1 = f1*pvec + g1*nvec;
p2 = f2*pvec + g2*nvec;
rels = {pvec.pvec, nvec.nvec, pvec.nvec - 1};
vars = Variables[{pvec, nvec}];
gb = GroebnerBasis[rels, vars];
Factor[PolynomialReduce[(p1 + p2).(p1 + p2), gb, vars][[2]]]

Out[44]= 2 (f1 + f2) (g1 + g2)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use expressions the `{p1,n1}` to represent your vectors, provided we define the inner product on our vector space and then write our equations in terms of the inner product.  For example, we can define the inner product and test it on the basis vectors like this:

```
Clear[dot]
dot[{a_, b_}, {x_, y_}] := a y + b x
p = {1, 0}; n = {0, 1};
{dot[p, n], dot[p, p], dot[n, n]}

(*  {1, 0, 0}  *)
```

We should interpret the result as a list of scalars, not a vector.

Suppose we want to find a unit vector, `p2` that is orthogonal to a given vector `p3`.  We can use `dot` in `Solve` like this

```
p1 = {1, -8};
p2 = {s, t};
soln = Solve[{dot[p1, p2] == 0, dot[p2, p2] == 1}, p2]

(*  {{s -> -1/4, t -> -2}, {s -> 1/4, t -> 2}}  *)
```

We have two solutions.  We can check the solutions by taking the `dot` products, as

```
p2a = p2 /. soln[[1]];
p2b = p2 /. soln[[2]];
{dot[p1, p2a], dot[p1, p2b], dot[p2a,p2a], dot[p2b, p2b]}

(*  {0, 0, 1, 1}  *)
```

Again, we interpret the result as a list of scalars.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) to setup your symbolic vectors `p` and `n`.

I will use script letter variables to hold the symbolic vectors. These can be entered with keyboard shortcuts.  For example for script-p ($p$) type <kbd>Esc</kbd>scp<kbd>Esc</kbd>. See more in the [Notational Alphabet Characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NotationalAlphabetCharacters.html) guide.

```
\[ScriptP] = Indexed[p, #] & /@ Range[4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
\[ScriptN] = Indexed[n, #] & /@ Range[4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Script letters $p$ and $n$ now hold symbolic vectors for `p` and `n` respectively. $p$ and $n$ can be used to define your symbolic vectors.

```
p1 = -2*k/(x + k)*y*\[ScriptP] - (k/x + m/y)*\[ScriptN]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The elements of $p$ and $n$ can assigned values through `p` and `n`.

```
p = Range[4];
n = Range[4];
\[ScriptP]
\[ScriptN]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

`p1` will update as well.

```
p1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The elements of $p$ and $n$ can be set back to the symbolic vector by `Unset`'ing `p` and `n`. This also reverts `p1` back to its symbolic representation.

```
p =.;
n =.;
p1
```

Hope this helps.